# Waiting 60 more seconds for network configuration

Tags: boot, networking

My laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) is taking too long showing a message "Waiting 60 more seconds for network configuration"

Comment: Look at /var/log/syslog and/or dmesg at the boot sequence for clues. Also look at the right of the page we are on at all of the "Related" questions `-------->`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/ubuntu-14-04-incredibly-slow-boot-without-network-4175510497/). Commenting out the lines that read "sleep 40" and "sleep 59" in /etc/init/failsafe.conf solved my problem. Saved the file after commenting, and then reboot. Now, my laptop is booting faster.